# Operate with a variable passed by a box

Tags: python, pepper, choregraphe

I'm working with a real pepper and Choregraphe.
I have a dialog that grab the input of a string (numbers 1 to 6) and inserts them into a specific output string.
Then i created a custom box in python to convert that string into number and do operations (put a counter or add the variables it receives in input).
To test the operation of "taking the variable" I created this if, but it does not work.
Can you tell me the correct syntax to use to take the input parameter?

[click here for the photo of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnPxi.png)

Comment: After reading this I have no clue what are you asking about. Post code.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot it XD i put a link

Comment: Dont link your code, paste it in your question.

Comment: def onInput_onStart(self, value, word):
        value = self.getParameter(word);
        if (value == "one"): self.onStopped()
        else: selfonStopped1()
        #self.onStopped() #activate the output of the box

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code (with proper formatting - the {} button), not addit as a comment (there's an edit button in the bottom left).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems with your code:

- The parameter you're getting is the "value" parameter of your function, you don't need the `value = self.getParameter(word)` line. `self.getParameter` is for getting box parameters (edited with the wrench at the bottom left corner of a box), which you don't seem to have on that box.
- You're getting a second parameter, "word", which seems useless and may even cause problems (did you add it? Normally there should only be one parameter)
- You shouldn't put the self.onStopped() on the same line as the if
- the second branch of your "if" is missing a dot: `selfonStopped1`.
- You should give meaningful names to your outputs

(it might be worth spending some time doing Python and Choregraphe tutorials, like [these](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/getting_started/creating_applications/index.html))